# Can I combine 3x 1000ma power supplies (wall warts) to get a 3amp supply [answer: no]

Tags: power-supply, parallel

I have a device that requires 3A, 9V.  I also have three 1A power supplies (wall warts).

Can I cut the wires of these power supplies, reconnect them all together in parallel, and use them all as a single 3amp 9v power supply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that they will have slightly different output voltages, and the one with the highest voltage will be supplying most of the load and will be overloaded.

Just buy a suitable 3A supply.

Comment: Is there a simple circuit I could build to pull power evenly from all sources?

Comment: No, there isn't!

Comment: maybe there is: http://nz.wellforces.com/resources/parallel-operation-power-supply/620/#.VdpHIfmqhBd

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Yes, you can do that because 9V AC adapter usually has 15V voltage reading when not loaded, and when you connect them together in parallel, your load will act as a voltage regulator for all three AC adapters. Just make sure to add a diode to each output to prevent burning out other 2 AC adapters when first one is plugged in, while the two others are not.

Comment: Most modern supplies are regulated switchers.

Comment: This answer is just making a guess as to what the supplies are and what their capabilities/limits are.  Just tossing in some isolation diodes does not in any way guarantee that the load will be shared equally.  Actually, it pretty much guarantee's that one supply will source the entire load until it fails, then the next, then the next.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution explained on following page: [here](http://nz.wellforces.com/resources/parallel-operation-power-supply/620/#.VdopS_mqhBc)
Take a look at figure 7.8 and 7.9 i think if you make a combination of those it might work.
place a resistor and diode at the positive output and connect them parallel

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.  You should edit some of the detail into your reply or convert it into a comment.

Comment: That page mentions a number of solutions. You should at the very least identify which one you think applies in this case. (IMO one might - but then again, maybe not.)

Comment: thnx for the advice, I edited my post